# Creating shapefile with attributes from mySQL using ogr2ogr

Tags: shapefile, ogr2ogr, mysql

I have some geometry which can be perceived as regions within a country and wish to create a shapefile which contains all the regions along with some attributes (e.g. name, population, area code, etc.)

I have the geometry from the regions in x,y WGS84 lat lon (not polygons so cannot be sure they are closed loops which is priority) currently stored in mySQL.

How do I create a single shapefile (with associated dbf and shx files) to contain this data using ogr2ogr?

Answer (score 3):

Try with `ogr2ogr` using something like:

```
ogr2ogr output.shp MYSQL:dbname,user=userid,password=password,host=host,port=3306 tablename
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it worked with:

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile"  C:/......./pms/pms.shp MySQL:dbgeom,host=webgis.bla.intern,user=bla,password=bla tablename -lco engine=MYISAM
```